# Bumblebee unable to load nvidia-uvm without sudo

Tags: nvidia, graphics, bumblebee, cuda, opencl

Apparently `nvidia-uvm` is only loaded with `sudo`. I'm using `nvidia-352` driver, so I added in my `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` file the next line

```
alias nvidia-uvm nvidia_352_uvm
```

Thus, the optirun command should be able to load nvidia-uvm when using cuda or opencl. Then, I see my programs working only when using "sudo optirun", so in order to test if the module itselfs loads, I put the following line:

```
$ optirun modprobe nvidia-uvm
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_352_uvm': Operation not permitted
```

When I do `sudo optirun modprobe nvidia-uvm` there's no error message and the module is loaded.

I can just imagine that Bumblebee doesn't have the right to access `nvidia_352_uvm` without root, which is weird because it can access `nvidia_352` for openGL programs (`optirun glxspheres64` for example is working fine).

Comment: Is your non root user added to the bumblebee group?

Comment: Of course it is, therefor OpenGL programs are working perfectly fine `optirun glxspheres64` for example. Also, when this program is running I can see `/dev/nvidia0` and `/dev/nvidiactl` mounted. And for example when using `optirun clinfo` (to test opencl) I need to run it with `sudo` or else `/dev/nvidia-uvm` is not mounted (nvidia-uvm is needed for opencl and cuda), and it should be able to run without using sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a working answer from the github community (https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/707). It turns out that I just needed to install `nvidia_modprobe` which somehow allows bumblebee to get the proper permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've got a slight issue with a new monitor of mine (see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/709233/dell-2715h-flickering-on-a-thinkpad-w530-running-lubuntu-14-04lts) and your info may come in handy. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean and reboot with vesa-standard and then re-install nvidia the different way :

With this I refer to the link given here :

Anyone has successfully installed CUDA 7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS x86_64?

There is Method A and Method B explained by me :

First of course clean the non-suiting installations with :

```bash
sudo apt-get remove bumblebee
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo reboot
```

For place reasons only Method A here :

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
```

or is this working ?:

```bash
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime ?
sudo reboot
```

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bumblebee
>
> sudo reboot

Due to your older graphicscard nvidia-355 nvidia-prime might be sufficient !

Happy coding and merry x-mas. If you need absolutely bumblebee, you can add it back in the end (due to a demanding program).

Comment: I see you took your time to write. But I absolutely need bumblebee, because nvidia-prime makes my computer hot because of the use of the GPU for the simples things, and since it's a laptop, it's not comfortable to type on a hot keyboard and also the battery is consumed faster. Bumblebee allows me to run only the application I want with the GPU, the problem is that for applications using cuda and opencl I need to run it with sudo because it cannot load the `nvidia-uvm` kernel module without permissions (god knows why).

Comment: @silgon - yes I have written - first uninstall bumblebee - and in the end you can re-install bumblebee - see last line (due to a demanding program) !