# Dell 2715H flickering on a Thinkpad W530 running Lubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, lubuntu, xorg

I just got the Dell 2715H and hooked it up to my Thinkpad W530 via the docking station's DisplayPort. The laptop has an nVidia K1000M with 2GB of memory. The monitor is detected fine using both the nouveau and the proprietary nVidia drivers, but in both cases seems to cut out periodically.

I've tried multiple configurations using xorg.conf, lxrandr and the nVidia X server config utility, but to no avail.  In all cases the monitor will periodically go black (as if going into power save mode) and then come back.  If I boot the laptop (while docked) with the laptop lid open, the monitor tends to stay 'on' longer.

I really have no idea what to try next. I've gone through:
 - nouveau with/without xorg.conf
 - nVidia with/without xorg.conf
 - [these directions](http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2012/08/enabling-external-monitor-on-lenovo.html)

Any and all suggestions will be appreciated.

Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4160 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1600x900       60.2*+   50.0  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 connected 2560x1440+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440      60.0*+
   2048x1152      60.0  
   1920x1200      59.9  
   1920x1080      60.0     59.9     50.0     30.0     25.0     24.0     60.1     60.0     50.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
   1200x960       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0     50.1  
   720x480        59.9     60.1  
   640x480        75.0     59.9     59.9
```

Current xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"

  # Removed Option "Xinerama" "off"
  Identifier     "Default Layout"
  Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
  InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
  InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
  Option         "Xinerama" "0"
  Option         "AIGLX" "on"
EndSection

Section "Files"
  ModulePath      "/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg"
  ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
  FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
  FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
  FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
  FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
  FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
  FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
  FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
  FontPath        "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
  FontPath        "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
  Identifier     "Mouse0"
  Driver         "mouse"
  Option         "Protocol" "auto"
  Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
  Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
  Identifier     "Keyboard0"
  Driver         "kbd"
  Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"
  Option         "XkbLayout" "us+inet"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier     "Monitor0"
  VendorName     "Unknown"
  ModelName      "DELL U2715H"
  HorizSync       30.0 - 113.0
  VertRefresh     56.0 - 86.0
  Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier     "Device0"
  Driver         "nvidia"
  VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
  BoardName      "Quadro K1000M"
  Option         "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
  BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier     "Screen0"
  Device         "Device0"
  Monitor        "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth    24
  Option         "Stereo" "0"
  Option         "metamodes" "DFP-5: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
  Option         "SLI" "Off"
  Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
  Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
  SubSection     "Display"
     Depth       24
  EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
  Option         "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection
```

Comment: A quick update: Based on some more research, it would appear that there may be underlying issues with the BIOS and its use of the display port(s). I'll update the BIOS to the latest version and see if that helps.

Comment: Updating the BIOS did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by:

1. Upgrading the version of Lubuntu to 15.10 (no xorg.conf).
2. Switching out the OEM DP -> mDP cable in favor of a DP -> DP.

I still get the flickering (going into power-save mode) on startup during the bios boot screens, but once grub takes over, everything settles in nicely.

For the record, another setup with a Dell M4400 running Fedora 21 (LXDE) did not have the issue, which is what led me to try to upgrade Lubuntu.

While I am using the proprietary nVidia drivers (v352) on my Lubuntu setup, the monitor works just as well with the Dell notebook running neuveau.

Did not anticipate upgrading my monitor setup would devour a week of my time...